# Get data from source in openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

How do I make the source data automatically load, even without adding the layer to the map?
I have the following code:

```
var layer1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'Layer1',
    visible: true,
    name: 'layer1',     
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon( ({
            anchor: [0.5, 26],
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
            src: 'legend/layer1.png'
        }))
    }),
    source:  new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
        return urlGeoserver + 'wfs?service=WFS&' +
            'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:LAYER1&' +
            'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
            'all=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
    })
});

layer1.getSource().on('featuresloadend', (vectorSourceEvent) => { 
    alert(vectorSourceEvent.features?.length); //return 0
})
```

This way it returns 0, but there are several features. It only returns correct if the layer is added to the map: map.addLayer(layer1);
How to solve, so that you can have access to the source, even without having added the layer?

[EDIT]: Following a tip from Mike, with fetch, it still doesn't show the data.

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();

var layer1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'Layer1',
    visible: true,
    name: 'layer1',     
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon( ({
            anchor: [0.5, 26],
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
            src: 'legend/layer1.png'
        }))
    }),
    source:  vectorSource,
});

    
var url = urlGeoserver + 'wfs?service=WFS&' +            
'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:LAYER1&' + 
'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326';

fetch(url)
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (json) {
        const features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(json);
        vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
    });

map.addLayer(layer1); //not return in map
```

Answer (score 1):

You can populate a vector source by fetching the url, parsing the features and adding them to the source.

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
fetch(url)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (json) {
    const features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(json);
    vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
    alert(features.length); 
  });
```

Comment: taking into account the source url is `urlGeoserver + 'wfs?service=WFS&' +
            'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:LAYER1&' +            'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
            'all=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';`, what would the fetch look like? Could this be the same url? I did not understand.

Comment: `&all=` is not a valid wfs parameter - I assume you meant bbox but that is not applicable when using `ol.loadingstrategy.all`so you could simply terminate after `outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326`

Comment: I edited the code, it still doesn't work.

Comment: The `featuresloadend` event only fires when features are loaded by the map.  The features are those added in the fetch callback.

Comment: Okay, I edited the code. I don't know where the error is, but even adding the layer to the map, it doesn't show the data.

Comment: What projection is your map view using?  The url is requesting data as EPSG:4326, if the view is different you need will need `features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(json, {dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection());`

Comment: I'm using EPSG:4326 anyway. In the first layer creation code layer1, with direct source, adding in the map, shows the data. What it wasn't showing was the total features of the source without adding the layer to the map. Now it doesn't show the layer on the map.